# Why THREE.WebGLRenderer.setPixelRatio() on computer is slower than mobile?

Tags: three.js

In the main js script I have below properties for the renderer

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(10) // 2 is good enough for pixel ratio but I just want to play around and set to 10.
```

My render became really smooth, on both google chrome desktop and mobile. However on my desktop which is using rtx2060 super, the fps is very low around 10fps, and on my mobile there is no drop on fps. I could not debug the issue.

Answer (score 3):

> renderer.setPixelRatio(10)

Please don't do that. This line will produce a final drawing buffer size which will be problematic for most devices. In almost all use cases, `setPixelRatio()` should be used like so in order to render at the native screen resolution:

```js
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
```

It's not recommended to experiment with different values other than `window.devicePixelRatio`.

Comment: "It's not recommended to experiment with different values". Actually, that is not a recommendation. There is nothing wrong with setting the pixel ratio to 1 or less to improve performance.

Comment: True, but I personally advise users not to use `setPixelRatio()` for downscaling resolutions. To me, `setSize()` is the better, semantically more clear method for this use case.

Comment: If users should not set values other than `window.devicePixelRatio`, `setPixelRatio()` would be removed from the API and the renderer would set it, instead.

Comment: You would need at least a method that enables/disables the usage of `window.devicePixelRatio`. Having `setPixelRatio()` for that is okay although alternative approaches are possible.